# How to make Android Apps designed for API 22 compatible with API21

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop, android-api-levels

I am new to android development and using Xamarin.Android so please keeps terminology simple and relevant if possible.

Current question is, are apps developed for API 22 (android 5.1) compatible with API 21 (android 5.0) by nature - i.e. without adding any package and stuff. If not, how do I make backwards compatibility possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you set a minimum SDK value, and a target SDK, and that says what API "range" your app runs against. You additionally compile with a particular SDK version, and that includes the code and resources for the app.

Most of the core API methods and classes are available starting at API 1.

If you want to include libraries, the support libraries should get you backwards compatible back to about API 7.

Answer (score 1):

> are apps developed for API 22 (android 5.1) compatible with API 21

If you use classes and methods which were introduced in API 22, then your app will not run on API 21. On the other hand, if you limit yourself to only methods available on API 21, then your app will run on both API 21 and API 22. For newer features, you can use the [Support Library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_4_-_providing_backwards_compatibility_with_the_android_support_package/).